# How to display combined rows in the database table with same ID

Tags: php, mysql, merge

i have a question for the experts. I have no idea how to combine all the order ID with the same ID,

like in the picture, all orders with order ID = 1 are in one transaction, how do i combine all order IDs with the same id and display only one total price for all of the proudcts bought. and since all order ID are the same so the deliver and payment option will also be the same just need to display one row.

and a follow up question is how will i also show all the products bought if i combine all the same order IDs, compute the total price and display delivery and payment option in one single row

[image]

Here is the picture for my database relationship, i just followed the ones on the internet. the only difference is that "products" are changed to "inventory" and "serial" in products are changed to "prod_id"

[image]

here are my codes to display the current picture.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = @mysql_select_db("");

$qry = "SELECT customers.name,customers.payment,customers.carrier, orders.date, order_detail.productid, order_detail.quantity, order_detail.price, order_detail.orderid, inventory.prod_name 
        FROM customers 
        RIGHT JOIN orders on customers.serial=orders.serial 
        RIGHT JOIN order_detail on orders.serial=order_detail.orderid 
        LEFT JOIN inventory on order_detail.productid=inventory.prod_id where customers.email='{$_SESSION['email']}'";

mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
echo "<center>";
echo "<table class='CSSTableGenerator'>
<tr>

<td>Date of Purchase</td>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Order ID</td>
<td>Products</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Total Price</td>
<td>Delivery Option</td>
<td>Payment Option</td>

<tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['orderid']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['prod_name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['quantity']."</td>";
echo "<td>".($row['price']*$row['quantity'])."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['carrier']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['payment']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
</table>
```

Comment: use sum(total_price) where id=1, when you have got your order id just selecting will fetch you the required details right then if the data is repeated then display it at the last count  that solves your problem, if you want you can normalize the tables so as to remove redundant data

Comment: that is we can have a seperate table which stores orderid, firstname,dateofpurchase,delivery option,payment option so redundancy is reduced. the orderid will be the common factor between the tables so as to get the data

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're needing to learn for this particular question is the SQL Group By clause.

This (untested, might need minor tweaking) should do the trick. Note that you don't get order item quantities out of this, but I would say that it's possible to get them.

```
SELECT o.date, c.name, o.serial as 'Order Id', GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) as 'Products', SUM(od.price) as 'Total', c.carrier, c.payment
FROM orders o
JOIN customers c on o.customer_id = c.serial
JOIN orderdetail od on o.serial = od.orderid
JOIN products p on od.productid = products.prod_id
GROUP BY o.serial
```

Of particular note is a handy aggregate function in MySQL called GROUP_CONCAT.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: what will it do? after it gets grouped by serial?

Comment: The Group By collects data across multiple records. So just by doing the group by you would be left with a single row. Then using the aggregate functions, such as sum(), avg(), or group_concat(), you can do calculations on all data in that group. So obviously sum(qty) combined with 'group by serial' would get the sum of the qty of all rows with that serial.